# Python requests login - the login page returned without an error

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a webpage using python requests and the result is the same login page, without any login error.

This is the login form:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" id="yw0" class="well form-horizontal">
        <div class="login">
                        <div class="form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="userInput" class="control-label required">Benutzer</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text"
                               name="loginName"
                               maxlength="32"
                               id="userInput">
                        <span style="display:none" 
                              class="help-inline error"
                              id="VierCom_Base_Models_LoginForm_username_em_"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="VierCom_Base_Models_LoginForm_password" class="control-label required">Passwort</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password"
                               name="loginPwd"
                               maxlength="32"
                               id="VierCom_Base_Models_LoginForm_password">
                            <span style="display: none"
                                  class="help-inline error"
                                  id="VierCom_Base_Models_LoginForm_password_em_"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <button type="submit"
                                name="btnLogin"
                                class="btn">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

This is my python code:

```
import requests
import re
import requests.utils, pickle
import argparse
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

user_field = "loginName"
pass_field = "loginPwd"

with requests.session() as c:
           login_url = 'https://login.professional-cockpit.de/login.php'
           after_login_url = 'https://login.professional-cockpit.de/qlikView.php'

           USERNAME = "*********"
           PASSWORD = "*********"
           c.get(login_url)

           login_data = dict(user_field=USERNAME,pass_field=PASSWORD)

           ### login to website
           res = c.post(login_url, data=login_data)

           print(res.text)
```

When i login from the browser, this is the Request headers:

```
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: login.professional-cockpit.de
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 51
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://login.professional-cockpit.de
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://login.professional-cockpit.de/login.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=g28c793759o9nthgrhd0p99536
```

I tried everything and googled this many times.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: just for testing purpose, try to pass hardcoded `Cookie`

Comment: I get the same result

Comment: Have you tried spoofing user-agent or referer ?

Comment: thanks. yes, i've tried adding both - Referer and User-Agent to the post request, still - no good :(

Answer (score 1):

Your payload isn't the required. Always use chrome's developers tab (networking) to outsource the real post/get informations

Use this payload

```
payload = {'loginName':user_field,
           'loginPwd':password_field,
           'btnLogin':''}
```

Your dict looks like this:

```
payload = {'user_field':user_field,
           'pass_field':pass_field}
```

The dict's keys don't have the same name of the real data, and you missed the btnLogin field. Sadly with any false information, the webserver will trash your request, because it has a specific "hard-coded" values which have to passed.

Comment: i don't know how i've missed that, but you're totally right! thank you very much.

Comment: I believe that the thing that was missing is the btnLogin, the user and password fields are variables.