# Python requests login - returned the same page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to do web scraping in my university page with the python package Requests, but I'm having trouble with the login. Here is the code from the login form:

```
<form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/Home/ValidaAcceso" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" title="Se necesita un nombre de Usuario" required
                   oninvalid="setCustomValidity('EL nombre de usuario es obligatorio')"
                   oninput="setCustomValidity('')" style="text-transform: lowercase;" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('La contraseña es obligatorio')"
                   oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
            <input type="hidden" id="navegador" name="navegador"  value="" />
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-info btn-login">Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="http://cuenta.fen.uchile.cl/olvido" target="_blank" class="btn btn-simple  center-block btn-login">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>

        </div>

        <hr>
        <div class="text-center">
            <p style="color:white; display: inline-block; padding-right:10px;">Acceso a: </p>
            <a  id="textButton" class="btn fen-btn-outline--white " href="http://pregrado.fen.uchile.cl/Pregrado/Login.aspx?Site=DocenciaWeb" target="_parent">Docenciaweb Antiguo</a>
            <p style="color:white; display: inline-block; padding-right:10px;">Disponible hasta el 15 de Julio 2018.</p>
        </div>
       
        <div class="login-footer2">
            <p>Cont&aacute;ctanos: <a style="color:white; display: inline-block; padding-right:10px;" class="  center-block"><strong>docenciaweb@fen.uchile.cl</strong></a></p>
            <p> © 2018 Docencia Web </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8CaYaKVR3I9EtAU8eK_rXx0FwjyHwMZF5z1LKRkLz2gzw1d6NGt7NMEKBBDF35xuNGwJlBtxs63_oBfRBn3OgfuiB6gyxybP4xiHPIIaZZgm8PXZLEeb9Q5LqNE-3Z3UctYWbEggO5BGnbtayZgLc4E" />
</form>
```

After checking some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316472/python-requests-login-the-login-page-returned-without-an-error/43319858) my python code is the following:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'usermane': 'myUser',
    'password': 'myPassword',
    'navegador': 'Netscape 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36',
    '__RequestVerificationToken': 'CfDJ8CaYaKVR3I9EtAU8eK_rXx0FwjyHwMZF5z1LKRkLz2gzw1d6NGt7NMEKBBDF35xuNGwJlBtxs63_oBfRBn3OgfuiB6gyxybP4xiHPIIaZZgm8PXZLEeb9Q5LqNE-3Z3UctYWbEggO5BGnbtayZgLc4E'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://docenciaweb.fen.uchile.cl/Home/ValidaAcceso', data=payload)
    page= s.get('https://docenciaweb.fen.uchile.cl/Home/MisCursos')
```

When I run this, I get always as a result the same page where I have to login. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: The page probably uses JavaScript which `requests` doesn't evaluate

Comment: The `__RequestVerificationToken` field is dynamic, which means you'll have to scrape it from the login page with `bs4` or `lxml`, or use `selenium`.